# How do I put an href link in an IOS App (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

My App is written in OpenGL and C++, I do not use XIB file for presentation. So how can I create an href link that the user clicks and takes them someone in the browser?

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL only draws things to the screen. There's no concept of geometric objects. So you'll have to detect a click on the link text and call the appropriate iOS API invoking the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found it:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevelopertips.com"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```